# How to show current Location on Android AVD?

Tags: android, google-maps

What am I missing, When I launch the app, it gives me the map of the whole world, How come it can't seem to set my current location knowing I specified it in code?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true); //show zoom controls

    currentLocation.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latitude));
    currentLocation.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(longtitude));

    //set MapType satellite
  //  mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    //show traffic
   // mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    //show my location
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng position) {
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(position)
                    .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                    .title("Marker")
                    .draggable(true);


            mMap.addMarker(options);
   }
```

Comment: But where you added marker on Google map?

Comment: @MD its not about marker. usually when you go to map, you will get your current location as blinking dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come it can't seem to set my current location knowing I specified
>   it in code?

To show current location in Map:

**1.** Get current location using `LocationManager`

**2.** Prepare `LatLng` object using `latitude` and `longtitude` which received in `onLocationChanged` method of `LocationListener` :

```
   LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longtitude);
```

**3.** Call `GoogleMap.moveCamera` to show coordinates :

```
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
```